cucumber hook execution order in parallel is not working
I have written cucumber tests with selenium framework. When my test ran in sequential they all pass, but when I run in parallel they fail because the same user is used for all the tests and the test is to login to app, change the language and verify the language, logout and log back in to verify the language for that user is persistent.
The issue is each test is to verify different language. So, the test 1 runs and during logout and log back in the second test already running and it changed the language. due to that the test 1 fails as the language is not same. For that I read online that using hooks might help in running test scenarios sequentially in parallel test. I did implement the hooks but still they are not working. Not sure if I am doing this correct.
Here is my feature file
@Profile @VerifyLanguageSetPortugues
Scenario Outline: Profile tests(Verify App Languages selection Espanol)
Given "guest" user login to app "DARTTS" using "AppAuth"
Then I verify previous language setting is active from app title "<Current AppTitle>"
And I click on language "<Language>"
Then I verify selected language for "<Field1>" "<Field2>" "<Field3>"
And I logout and log back in
And I verify previous language setting is active from app title "<Previous AppTitle>"
When I click on user profile button
Then I should log out of Raven app

Examples:
  | Language  | Current AppTitle  | Previous AppTitle       | Field1                                                                              | Field2                                                     | Field3                                      |
  | Português | Analyze           | Analisar | Clique no botão \"novo grupo de filtros\" para criar seu primeiro grupo de filtros. | Selecione um filtro para mostrar os resultados nesta tela. | Expandir explorar e tabular as estatísticas |

@Profile @VerifyLanguageSetEspanol
Scenario Outline: Profile tests(Verify App Languages selection Espanol)
Given "guest" user login to app "DARTTS" using "AppAuth"
Then I verify previous language setting is active from app title "<Current AppTitle>"
And I click on language "<Language>"
Then I verify selected language for "<Field1>" "<Field2>" "<Field3>"
And I logout and log back in
And I verify previous language setting is active from app title "<Previous AppTitle>"
When I click on user profile button
Then I should log out of Raven app

Examples:
  | Language | Current AppTitle | Previous AppTitle       | Field1                                                                                  | Field2                                                                       | Field3                                                    |
  | Español  | Analyze          | Analizar | Haga clic en el botón \"nuevo grupo de filtros\" para crear su primer grupo de filtros. | Seleccione un grupo de filtros para mostrar los resultados en esta pantalla. | Ampliar la exploración y las estadísticas de las columnas |

Hooks class
public class Hooks {
    @Before(order = 1, value = "@VerifyLanguageSetPortugues")
public void portuguesLangBeforeScenario() {
    System.out.println("This should run first");
}

@After(order = 4, value = "@VerifyLanguageSetPortugues")
public void portuguesLangAfterScenario() {
    System.out.println("This should end first");
}

@Before(order = 2,  value = "@VerifyLanguageSetEspanol")
public void espanolLangBeforeScenario() {
    UIPgAct.driverWait(55000);
    System.out.println("This should run second");
}

@After(order = 3,  value = "@VerifyLanguageSetEspanol")
public void espanolLangAfterScenario() {
    System.out.println("This should end second");
    System.out.println("Espanol language is set to true");
}

In the output I see the messages are printed right next to each message. The second scenario didn't wait until the first one is completed.
11:01:59.545 [TestNG-PoolService-1] INFO  gov.dhs.ice.raven.resources.base - Detected Dartts scenario tag.
    11:02:05.474 [TestNG-PoolService-0] INFO  gov.dhs.ice.raven.resources.base - WebDriver setup is complete
    This should run first
    11:02:05.548 [TestNG-PoolService-1] INFO  gov.dhs.ice.raven.resources.base - WebDriver setup is complete
    This should run second


Am I missing anything? Looks like your logs are saying that the order corresponds to what has been configured in your code?


When my test ran in sequential they all pass, but when I run in parallel they fail because the same user is used for all the tests and the test is to login to app, change the language and verify the language, logout and log back in to verify the language for that user is persistent. The issue is each test is to verify different language. So, the test 1 runs and during logout and log back in the second test already running and it changed the language. due to that the test 1 fails as the language is not same.

This is a typical example of a race condition. You have multiple threads modifying the same resource at the same time.
So you need to make sure that tests don't use the same user at the same time. There are many ways to accomplish this:

Don't run in parallel
As part of the test, create a new user for each test. Delete them when done.
Create several new users manually. Then use the object pool pattern to ensure each user is used by a single test at a time.


The first two options doesn't work as we are using 100+ test cases and if I have to run sequentially it will take couple hours to run the tests and for users we are using LDAP and we can't create test users in the applications. Anyhow I was able to achieve these tests run in sequential and the test cases are passing now. I have updated my hooks script above. But now I am getting another error java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can not use Scenario.log or Scenario.attach when a step is not being execute everytime I try to access TakeScreenshot method

Doesn't look like your edit came through. Anyway, best to write a new question than. It's how SO works.

actually this issue started after I implemented this Hooks. Till now I never got this error, so I thought of continuing the same ticket with this new issue. But I will create new one thanks

Please give this a careful read. It's important that you provide enough information for people to reproduce the problem. This will take work, quite a lot of it. But that's the price of asking random strangers on the internet for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
